# Context path is not working for SpringBoot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I gave below property in the **application.properties** file

`server.servlet.context-path=/api`

But when I am hitting the endpoint using Postman, I am getting endpoint not found error. I am new to SpringBoot so please help me. I am using Java 17 and SpringBoot 3.0.8

Comment: To what URL did you make a request and what in your application did you expect to handle that request? Can you provide a [complete, yet minimal example that reproduces the problem](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can't see where `rfn/rflist` comes from. It isn't mentioned anywhere in your question. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah I created a controller method using @GetMapping(/test). So I tried hitting endpoint localhost:8004/api/test and got endpoint not found error. But when I tried hitting just localhost:8004/test, I got the response.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my comment now.

Comment: You still haven't provided a complete yet minimal example. Without one, I don't think there's enough information in your question to figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson The issue got fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TusharAgarwal you're supposed to answer your own question to help people having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that issue was with the dependency. I was importing **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux** earlier. Netty is the default embedded container for webflux and it seems it doesn't support servlet context path. Once I replaced it with
**org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web**, it uses Tomcat as default embedded server which perfectly supports servlet context-path.

**org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux** builds the application using Spring Webflux whereas **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web** builds the application using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Use this property `server.servlet.contextPath=/api`. In startup logs you will see the following logger to confirm that contextPath is set `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path /api`

Comment: `server.servlet.contextPath` is the same as `server.servlet.context-path` that the OP is already using

Comment: Yes, but somehow `server.servlet.contextPath` is working when I tried it in my local and not `server.servlet.context-path` version for which I tried is spring boot `3.0.3`

Comment: For me both of them are not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had set the server.servlet.context-path value in my application.yml file but in the console the message was

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

Strangely, there was no problem running locally with IntelliJ but when I deployed to Openshift the context path was blank even though I could see the correct config coming from the config-server service. The answer for me was to add this Bean to my config class:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/my-context-path");
}
```

I was using Java 17, spring-boot-starter-parent 3.1.5, spring-cloud-starter-config 4.0.4